# PDO сверка пользователя с hash_password

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

в бд залиты пользователи с hash_password, при извлечении не пойму как сделать, чтобы пароль нормально проверялся. с PDO работаю первый день, камнями не кидаться =)
Вот мой кривокод:

```
    <?php
    require_once "libs/db.php";

    $data = $_POST;
    if(isset($data['do_login']))
    {
        $errors = array();
        $query = ('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE u_login = :login)');
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(['login' => $data['login']]);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($data['password'], $results['u_password'])) {
            echo "LOGGED IN";
        } else {
            echo "LOGGIN FAILED";
        }
    }

?>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <p>Ваш логин: <input type="text" name="login" value="<?= @$data['login']; ?>"></p>
    <p>Ваш Пароль: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?= @$data['password']; ?>"></p>
    <p><button type="submit" name="do_login">Войти</button></p>

</form>
```

Ошибка
Notice: Undefined index: u_password in C:\MAMP\htdocs\project1\login.php on line 12
LOGGIN FAILED

Подскажите где я тут накосячил, и как лучше это сделать можно было вообще.

Comment: нужен fetch вместо fetchAll.  Первый одну запись, второй набор.

Comment: попробовал - ошибка та же =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ошибка в запросе, вы проверяете наличие пользователя с определённым логином, а не загружаете данные этого пользователя. Нужно `SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_login = :login`.
2. fetchAll возвращает массив массивов (всю таблицу а не отдельную запись), Для того чтоб получить только 1 запись нужно делать fetch.

   ```
   if(isset($data['do_login']))
   { 
       $errors = [];
       $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_login = :login';
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
       $stmt->execute(['login' => $data['login']]);
       $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       if ($result && password_verify($data['password'], $results['u_password'])) 
       {
           echo "LOGGED IN";
       }
       else 
       {
           echo "LOGGIN FAILED";
       }
   }`
   ```

Comment: все заработало))) поправил еще   $query = ('SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_login = :login'); и все =)